# Pattern to match a non-empty list of non-empty lists

Tags: pattern-matching

**Is there a pattern to match a list of lists, containing at least one list, with each list containing at least one element?**

In the [Mathematica documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PatternsForSomeCommonTypesOfExpression.html) it says that the pattern

```
x:{___List}
```

will match a list of lists. This is true, but it also matches `{}`, which is a list of zero lists (or zero *anything*). To make sure there is at least one list in my list of lists I can remove one of the underscores to change `BlankNullSequence` to `BlankSequence`, i.e. switch to

```
x:{__List}
```

which no longer matches `{}`. It does, however, match `{{}}`. How can I also guarantee that each matched sublist is non-empty? Is this even possible, or should I be checking for it programmatically within the `Module` to which I'm passing arguments of this form?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If I am understanding you:

```
x : {{__} ..}
```

See [Repeated](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Repeated.html) for more information and additional options.  Also see [RepeatedNull](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RepeatedNull.html) while you're there.

Make sure you understand [BlankSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html) and [Pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html) as well.

---

Here is a breakdown of the expression above.  First let us view the `FullForm` which is as close to the way *Mathematica* sees it as possible:

```
FullForm[ x:{{__}..} ]
```

> ```
> Pattern[x,
>   List[
>     Repeated[
>       List[
>         BlankSequence[]
>       ]
>     ]
>   ]
> ]
> ```

This expanded form is useful to remove any ambiguity in *Mathematica's* parsing.

Therefore from the inside out we have (`short form` : `long form` : description):

`__` : `BlankSequence[]` : one or more arguments with any head

`{ }` : `List[ ]` : inside the head `List`

`..` : `Repeated[ ]` : one or more arguments matching the given pattern

`{ }` : `List[ ]` : inside the head `List`

`x:` : `Pattern[x, ]` : a unique expression that matches the given pattern, named `x`

Pay attention to this last point: naming the pattern changes the way it behaves, such that it represents a unique expression.  Consider this superficially similar pattern:

```
x : {{a__} ..}
```

This will only match e.g. `{{1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}}` but *not* `{{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5, 6}}` because by naming the first sequence `1, 2` all other sequences must be identical.  Simply matching the pattern `a__` independently is not enough.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to do the trick for all test cases I've come up with... Could you elaborate on this at all? Am I interpreting correctly that the outer braces simply hold the pattern, the inner ones represent a list, the two underscores say that list must have at least one element, and the two periods indicate that there must be at least one such non-empty list?

Comment: @Michael I added links to useful documentation.  The outer brackets are certainly part of the pattern (named `x`).  `{__}` stands for a list with one or more elements, and `..` is short form of `Repeated` which means one or more of the preceding expression.  Please read all four documentation pages that I link to above, then return with any further questions.

Comment: @MichaelUnderwood I'd also suggest reading this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7122094/198315) and its answer.

Comment: That's the one - +1.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to stick to the same pattern as your original you can also set up a test for empty lists as follows...

```
notEmptyListQ[x_List] /; Length[Flatten[x]] == 0 := False
notEmptyListQ[x_List] := True
```

Here I test it with a function `f`.

```
f[x : {___List?notEmptyListQ}] := True
f[___] := False

In[17]:= f[{{1}, {}}]

Out[17]= False

In[18]:= f[{{1}, {2}}]

Out[18]= True
```

Empty lists of arbitrary depth are excluded.

```
In[19]:= f[{{1}, {{{}}}}]

Out[19]= False
```

Checks like this can make code more readable (at least for me) and in some cases lessen the workload of the pattern matcher (though not so much in this case).

**Edit**: in order to prevent `f[{}]` from returning true, you would also have to check the outer list x if you insist on using `BlankNullSequence`.

That is...

```
f[x: {___List?notEmptyListQ}]/;notEmptyListQ[x]:= True
```

This is but one of the many good arguments against using `BlankNullSequence` unless you really need it.

Comment: Got to keep that answer to question ratio up :)

Comment: We're slipping a little, some questions only have 2 or 3 answers, not the customary 5 - 10. :)