# Elegantly split a matrix into positive and negative parts?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix $M$ of real components, and I want to split it into two matrices $M^+$ and $M^-$ of the same dimensions as $M$, where $M^+$ contains the positive components of $M$ (the remaining entries being filled with zeros), and $M^-$ contains the negative components, such that $M=M^+ + M^-$.

Suppose the matrices are represented in the usual way in Mathematica (as lists of lists, or as sparse arrays)

How can I do this efficiently and elegantly in Mathematica?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Clip` is usually quite fast:

```
m = RandomReal[{-10^6, 10^6}, {3, 3}];

neg = Clip[m, {-Infinity, 0}]
pos = Clip[m, {0, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> (*{{0., -181286., -442666.}, {0., -233694., -847828.}, {-128249., 0., -540037.}}
>
> {{947792., 0., 0.}, {755278., 0., 0.}, {0., 63058.1, 0.}}*)
> ```

```
neg + pos == m
```

> True

Comment: You might even save a few characters with things like `pos=m-neg`...

Comment: This is MUCH faster than mine!

Comment: I bet you didn't think this would be one of your most popular answers ever. +1 :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Innuendo :D  Only what that says about my average contribution,  I dare not dwell upon. I was also waiting for you to steal my thunder...

Comment: @Yves What it says is that your average contribution is more esoteric than these little nuggets that have popular appeal and that the voting system provides no way to differentiate between "interesting" and "mindbogglingly amazing."  Some of the answers I have put the most thought and effort into scored the lowest, while [something minor](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1277/121) dropped in passing scores highly.  [Occasionally](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121) something that took a lot of thought is apparently concise and general enough to be popular.

Answer (score 14):

You could also use the functions `Positive` and `Negative`:

```
m = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10, 10}];
pos = m Boole[Positive[m]];
neg = m Boole[Negative[m]];
```

give the positive and negative portions. As becko points out, replacing `Boole[Positive[mat]]` with `UnitStep[m]`:

```
pos = m UnitStep[m];
neg = m UnitStep[-m];
```

is even more succinct. These can even be combined into one line (as suggested by Mechanical Snail:

```
{pos, neg} = m*UnitStep[#] & /@ {m, -m}
```

Comment: +1 Instead of `Boole[Positive[mat]]`, you can also use `UnitStep[mat]`, and instead of `Boole[Negative[mat]]`, you can also use `UnitStep[-mat]`... No big improvement, just one function instead of two :)

Comment: Or in one line: `{pos, neg} = m * UnitStep /@ {m, -m}`

Answer (score 11):

This is yet another way:

```
mat = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10, 10}];
matPair = Map[Sort[{#, 0}] &, mat, {2}] // Transpose[#, {2, 3, 1}] &;

Grid[# /. {
           x_?NumericQ :> If[x < 0,
                 Item["", Background -> Darker[Red, .5]],
                 If[x > 0,
                    Item["", Background -> Darker[Green, .4]],
                    Item["", Background -> GrayLevel[.9]]]]
          }, Frame -> True, ItemSize -> {.4, 1}] & /@
 Prepend[matPair, mat]
```

[image: comparison]

It can be seen like this: transpose the 3rd level i.e. the {*negative*, *positive*} level to be the 1st level, and leave other levels untouched (thus level-down in order).

Comment: Darn - so blindingly obvious :D

Comment: Hey Silvia! Can you help me? http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/40424/2882

Comment: @belisarius man you should have asked *before* eating that!

Comment: @YvesKlett I live a perilous life

Comment: @belisarius Looks like some kind of pickles from Korea?

Comment: Really no idea :(

Comment: @belisarius Pleas see [my answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40431/22028) there :)

Comment: @belisarius - I [OCR](http://www.newocr.com)'d the chinese (高麗櫫葷乞) and google translated it: "Korea manifestation of the ideal meat begging".  I think the OCR got the middle character wrong.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Try google "高麗菜乾" :)

Comment: Hehe ... I love off-topic comments :) here

Comment: @ChrisDegnen "the ideal mind boggling" ? :)

Comment: @belisarius - Silvia's `Transpose` is mind boggling.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Looks like Chinese to me :)

Comment: @ChrisDegnen It can be seen like this: transpose the 3rd level i.e. the {-,+} level to be the first level, and leave other levels untouched (thus level-down in order).

Answer (score 10):

Another one for fun.

Positive:

```
(m + Abs[m])/2
```

Negative:

```
(m - Abs[m])/2
```

Comment: +1 Instead of Sqrt[m^2], you can also use Abs[m].

Comment: my only quarrel with this solution is that you could run into numerical issues.

Comment: @becko That's better, thanks.

Comment: @YvesKlett The switch to `Abs` partly fixes this in that `Abs` will warn when it reaches the precision limit. Addition and division by two shouldn't be a problem, I think.

Comment: Also, `Abs[-m]` is the same as `Abs[m]`.

Comment: @becko Naturally lol, what a mistake.

Answer (score 7):

An approach using `UnitStep`:

```
{pos, neg} = With[{u = UnitStep}, {# u@#, # u@-#}] &@mat
```

or with `Positive` and `Negative`:

```
{pos, neg} = {#, #} Boole@Through[{Positive, Negative}@#] &@mat
```

Comment: Go obfuscious (^_-)

Comment: +1... Are you using `With[{u = UnitStep}, ...]` just to save characters? You're not helping the OP :(

Comment: @becko I would never use something like that to save characters... that's Mr.Wizard's modus operandi :) In fact, this takes _more_ characters than just writing out `UnitStep` in both places. It must've been the wine... Also, why are you referring to yourself in the third person? o_O

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way...

```
mat = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10, 10}];

{neg, pos} = {mat /. x_ /; x > 0 -> 0, mat /. x_ /; x < 0 -> 0};


neg+pos==mat
```

> `True`

And here's another way using `Map`:

```
{neg, pos} = {Map[Min[#, 0] &, mat, {2}], Map[Max[#, 0] &, mat, {2}]}
```

Comment: `neg` and `pos` is somehow universal :D

Comment: @YvesKlett, Oh, I like your `Clip` method...

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[0];
list = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {5, 5}];

pos = #[1]& @* GroupBy[Sign] /@ list
```

{{10}, {6, 9}, {2, 7, 1}, {2, 8}, {5}}

```
neg = #[-1]& @* GroupBy[Sign] /@ list
```

{{-6, -8, -8, -3}, {-8, -8, -7}, {-9}, {-9, -8, -9}, {-7, -10, -8,
-1}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Cases` and `Map`:

```
SeedRandom[0];(*Thanks to eldo*)
list = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {5, 5}];

Map[Cases[#, x_ /; Sign[x] == 1] &, list]

{{10}, {6, 9}, {2, 7, 1}, {2, 8}, {5}}

Map[Cases[#, x_ /; Sign[x] == -1] &, list]

{{-6, -8, -8, -3}, {-8, -8, -7}, {-9}, {-9, -8, -9}, {-7, -10, -8, -1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];
mat = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {10, 10}];
```

#### [`Ramp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ramp.html)

```
pos = Ramp[mat];
neg = - Ramp[-mat];

pos + neg == mat
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
MinMax @ Sign @ pos
```

> ```
> {0, 1}
> ```

```
MinMax @ Sign @ neg
```

> ```
> {-1, 0}
> ```

#### Visualization

```
labeledMatrixPlot = MatrixPlot[ToExpression @ #, 
    ColorRules -> {_?Negative -> Red, _?Positive -> Darker@Green, _ -> White}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, 
    Mesh -> All, 
    Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[#, 12], #2 - 1/2] &, 
      Transpose @ Reverse @ #2, {2}], 
    PlotLabel -> #] &;

Row[labeledMatrixPlot[#, mat] & /@ {"mat", "pos", "neg"}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
WolframLanguageData["Ramp", "VersionIntroduced"]
```

> ```
> 11
> ```