# Replacing matrix values

Tags: matrix, algorithm, performance-tuning

I want to find the n largest values in a matrix and replace all others with zero.

The solution I found uses `ReplaceAll` and becomes very slow as the size of matrices grows:

```
FindLargestValues[m_?MatrixQ, n_Integer] :=
  With[{v = (Union @ Flatten @ m)[[-n]]},
    m /. x_Real /; x < v :> 0]
```

Example:

```
(small = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {5, 5}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
FindLargestValues[small, 10] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Timing example:

```
large = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {50, 50}];

Do[FindLargestValues[large, 50], {1000}]; // Timing // First
```

> 2.574016

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41478/131 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39113/131

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that the values of your matrix are all distinct, or that you don't count repetitions in `n`, you can do this:

```
ClearAll[largest];
largest[mat_, n_] := Clip[mat,{RankedMax[#, n], Max[#]}, {0, 0}] &[Flatten@mat]
```

So that

```
large = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {50, 50}];
Do[largest[large, 50], {1000}]; // Timing // First

(* 0.076633 *)
```

Comment: Beat me to it! +1 :-)

Comment: Your assumptions are right +1

Comment: ah, `Clip`, me old favorite!

Comment: It seems a teeny bit faster to use `Infinity` in place of `Max[#]`

Comment: @SimonWoods Somehow I seemed to recall that Infinity might unpack, so didn't use it. Perhaps, I was wrong - I didn't test it this time.

Answer (score 9):

I can't test the timing right now, but maybe it's worth mentioning

```
Threshold[large, {"LargestValues", 50}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a relative minor variation on eldo's method that speeds it up considerably, but still falls well short of Lenonid Shifrin's better algorithm.

```
 keepMax[matrix_, n_] :=
   With[{threshold = (Union@Flatten@matrix)[[-n]]},
     Map[If[# < threshold, 0, #] &, matrix, {2}]]
```

Absolute timings

```
SeedRandom[42]; testData = RandomInteger[{1, 99}, {50, 50}];
eldo = (Do[FindLargestValues[testData, 50], {1000}]; // Timing // First)
```

> ```
> 1.218814
> ```

```
shif = (Do[largest[testData, 50], {1000}]; // Timing // First)
```

> ```
> 0.088629
> ```

```
mg = (Do[keepMax[testData, 50], {1000}]; // Timing // First)
```

> ```
> 0.446820
> ```

Comparative timings

```
{eldo/mg, mg/shif, eldo/shif}a
```

> ```
> {2.72775, 5.0415, 13.752}
> ```

Further, it would seem that my computer is faster than eldo's but a little slower than Shifrin's.

Answer (score 1):

I wondered if compiling was worth a shot...

You can go a little faster than @SimonWoods' answer of `Threshold[large, {"LargestValues", 50}]`.

```
large = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {50, 50}];

FindLargestValues = Compile[{{matrix, _Real, 2}, {n, _Integer}},
   Module[{minvalue},
    minvalue = (Union@Flatten@matrix)[[-n]];
    Chop[matrix, minvalue]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

Do[FindLargestValues[large, 50], {1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.151 seconds *)

Do[Threshold[large, {"LargestValues", 50}], {1000}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.270 seconds *)
```

But still @LeonidShifrin's answer wins out (and contains functions that cannot be compiled anyway).

```
largest[mat_, n_] := 
 Clip[mat, {RankedMax[#, n], Max[#]}, {0, 0}] &[Flatten@mat]

Do[largest[large, 50], {1000}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(* 0.044 seconds *)
```