# Check whether array has only constant entries?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I have an array `arr` with `n` entries. Now I want to check whether

```
arr[[1]]==arr[[2]]&&arr[[2]]==arr[[3]]&&...arr[[n-1]]==arr[[n]]
```

Of course I could use a `for`-loop, like

```
arr = {0, 1, 0, 0};
IsConst = True;
For[i = 1, i <= Length[arr], i++,
  If[arr[[i]] != arr[[1]],
    IsConst = False;
    i = Length[arr];
  ];
];
Print[IsConst];
```

But that doesn't look too fast, so I wonder whether there is a faster way.

Comment: `Union` or `DeleteDuplicates` and then if the resulting list has length greater than 1 then the elements are not all the same (not constant in your terminology)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [`Apply (@@)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Equal.html) to your list:

```
constantQ = Equal@@#&;

constantQ @ {0,1,0,0}
(* False *)
```

or

```
constantQ2 = Max@#==Min@# &;
constantQ3 = Variance@#==0;
constantQ4 = Length@DeleteDuplicates@# == 1 &;
```

See also: [SameQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SameQ.html)

```
constantQ5 = SameQ @@ #&

Equal @@ {1, 1., 1}
(* True *)
SameQ @@ {1, 1., 1}
(* False *)
```

...

Comment: That looks nice, very interesting solutions (I should, at some point, really understand that kind of instructions you show). Thanks!

Comment: @NicoDean, my pleasure..

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why people don't like `DeleteDuplicates` :)

```
Length@DeleteDuplicates@arr > 1
```

for me this is faster than other methods (using V9 OS X tonight)

Answer (score 3):

```
If[Length[Tally[arr]] == 1, IsConst = True, IsConst = False]
```

Comment: `If` is redundant here: `IsConst = Length@Tally@arr == 1`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the fastest is... just to compile the OP code

```
sameQ = Compile[{{arr, _Integer, 1}},
   Module[{IsConst = True, i},
    For[i = 1, i <= Length[arr], i++,
     If[arr[[i]] != arr[[1]],
      IsConst = False;
      Break[];
      ]];
    IsConst], CompilationTarget -> "C", "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"];

arr = ConstantArray[1, 10000000];
arr[[-1]] = 0;

sameQ[arr] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.027877, False} *)

constantQ4@arr // AbsoluteTiming (* fastest kguler's test *)
(* {0.062203, False} *)
```

Comment: Oh wow. That's exactly why I love SE :D

Comment: One of these days I really should install a C compiler...

Answer (score 2):

This problem is in a manner an converse of [How do you check if there are any equal arguments(even sublist) in a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6745/121) and is related to [How do I check if any element in a list is positive?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8650/121) As with both of those there is a choice in approach of either scanning the entire light with a fast, vectorized operation, or providing for an early-exit behavior.  Which one is desirable will depend on the most commonly tested expression form.  Please review my answer to the second linked question for examples.

Using `Tally` or `Max` and `Min` are examples of methods that scan the entire list without the possibility of an early exist.

The length of the list can also affect the performance of the methods used.  For example, as noted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6745/how-do-you-check-if-there-are-any-equal-argumentseven-sublist-in-a-list#comment22176_7619) `UnsameQ` works well on short lists (few arguments) but not on long ones.   That doesn't appear to be the case with `Equal` and `SameQ` however so both of those are good general methods for your problem, and provide early exist behavior.  You can choose between numeric and structural equivalence.  kguler already showed these but repeated for completeness:

```
Equal @@ {1, 1, 1, 1}
SameQ @@ {1, 1, 1, 1}
```

> ```
> True
> True
> ```

```
Equal @@ {1, 1, 2, 1}
SameQ @@ {1, 1, 2, 1}
```

> ```
> False
> False
> ```

```
Equal @@ {1, 1, 1.0, 1}
SameQ @@ {1, 1, 1.0, 1}
```

> ```
> True
> False
> ```

To bring a unique method to this answer we can also use pattern matching for structural equivalence:

```
MatchQ[{1, 1, 1, 1}, {x_ ..}]
MatchQ[{1, 1, 2, 1}, {x_ ..}]
```

> ```
> True
>
> False
> ```

By *naming* the [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) (`x_`) we restrict it to matching a particular expression.  See:

- [Pattern to match a non-empty list of non-empty lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1276/121)

Comment: w.r.t. to timings, users should be reminded that `Apply` will unpack. Therefore `MatchQ` or checking the length of a deleted duplicates list may well be better options for packed arrays of larger length

Comment: @Mike Indeed.  The issue of unpacking is mentioned in my answer to "How do I check if any element in a list is positive?" which I intend for people to read.  I chose not to repeat myself here but instead direct readers to the earlier questions.

Comment: no worries. Am watching the cricket, having a beer, and reading this ...am not a multi tasker!