# Delete efficiently rows of empty list elements inside a list

Tags: list-manipulation

What is the most efficient method for deleting a row of empty list elements? For example, here is a list with one row of empty list elements:

```
list = {{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {0, 0, 0},
    {4, 5, 6}
    },
   {{}, {}, {}},
   {
    {1, 2, 3},
    {0, 0, 0},
    {4, 5, 6}
    }};
```

I want to get rid of the whole of row 2. Using `DeleteCases[]`:

```
DeleteCases[list, x_ /; x == {}, Infinity]
```

...which returns:

```
{{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}, **{}**, {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 
   6}}}
```

How can I efficiently delete the 2nd row without using `DeleteCases[]` twice?

Comment: `DeleteCases[list, {{} ..}]`

Comment: As an aside, if your list "empties" are *known* to have the same structure, you can get a nice performance boost by specifying the exact pattern, e.g. `DeleteCases[list, {{}, {}, {}}]` in your example.

Comment: Related: [(1276)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1276/121),
[(20180)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20180/121)

Comment: Why close votes for "does not concern software Mathematica ..." reason?!

Comment: Related: "[Efficient way to remove empty lists from lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6562902/590388)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have the same interpretation of OP requirements as others seem to, but here's my take on those interpretations:

```
DeleteCases[#, Nest[{# ...} &, {}, Depth[#]], Infinity] &@b
```

Where *b* is of course the target list.

Unless `Nothing` performs much faster than the use of `Sequence[]`, this seems to do quite well against what appears to be the fastest "get rid of any empty list anywhere" solution.

Edit: I used this to generate test b:

```
b = 
 RandomChoice[
  {9, 1, 1, 1, 9} -> 
   {{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
    {{}, {}, {}}, {{}, {{{}, {{}}, {}}}, {}}, {{}}, 
    {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {{{{{{{{{{{{1, 2, 3, {{{}, {1, 2, 3}}}}}}}}}}}}}}},
     {1,2, 3, {}}}}, 1000000];
```

Comment: Nice example. I spent a little time figuring out how this works. Would I be correct in saying that in this case, the condition in the DeleteCases function is the a representation of the empty list structure? Doing this causes the DeleteFunction to delete empty lists in one go without mapping or nesting DeleteCases? Thanks to all who gave their time to help me.

Comment: @awyr_agored: Yes, though what "one go" means *under the covers* can vary. In any case, it handily outperformed in my tests, glad you find in useful and interesting.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a very simple and concise construct for doing what you ask.

```
a = 
  {{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
   {{}, {}, {}}, 
   {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}};
a //. {} -> Nothing
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
>  {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}}
> ```

It has the advantage of working for `{ }` appearing at any level.

```
b = 
  {{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
   {{}, {}, {}}, 
   {{}, {{{}, {{}}, {}}}, {}}};
b //. {} -> Nothing
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}}
> ```

Note that I used the very useful new symbol `Nothing`. This means the above solution only works for V10.2 or later.

Comment: Since OP mentions "efficient", I think this will be considerably slower than `DeleteCases` on large lists...

Comment: @ciao I am actually having trouble beating by a large margin.  `DeleteCases` by itself doesn't get everything in one pass.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Perhaps I've misread the question - can you give an example? The OP says nothing about "arbitrarily nested..."

Comment: @ciao I mean for the case of arbitrary nesting; using m_goldberg's `b` if we do `DeleteCases[b, {{} ...}, {0, -1}]` we still end up with `{{{}}}` in the output.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Ah, well unless `Nothing` is way faster than `Sequence`, `FixedPoint[DeleteCases[#, {{} ..}, -1] &, list]` is faster on the loungebook on v9 for big lists with arbitrary nesting of empties.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I missused the term 'efficient'. I should have said if I could solve the problem without having to nest the DeleteCases function.

Answer (score 10):

For arbitrarily nested lists one could also use [`MapAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAll.html) and the operator form of [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html):

```
b = (* m_goldberg's example *)
  {{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
   {{}, {}, {}}, 
   {{}, {{{}, {{}}, {}}}, {}}};

DeleteCases[{}] //@ b
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}}
> ```

It works via the bottom-up standard evaluation order.

This however is somewhat slower than `//.` in a single test.  Using an anonymous function instead of the operator form is a little faster than `//.` however in the same test, though less clean:

```
DeleteCases[#, {}] & //@ b
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}}
> ```

Comment: Give `DeleteCases[Map[Flatten, b, {2}], {{} ..}]` a whirl...

Comment: for fun i was going to post `FixedPoint[# /. {} -> Sequence[] &, b]` but pointless really...felt like popping bubblewrap.

Comment: @ubpdqn or like this :`b//. {} -> Sequence[]`

Comment: @ShutaoTANG yes I was being silly...and ReplaceAll is what I use a lot...I guess is not about DeleteCases...:-)

Comment: Thanks ubqdqn. Elegant code - I should have looked at the problem from a different perspective.

Answer (score 4):

This one performs nicely also:

```
f[{}]=Sequence[];
f[x_]:=x;

f //@ {{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{}, {}, {}}, {{}, {{{}, {{}}, {}}}, {}}};
```

> `{{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}}`

Here are some interesting ***relative timings*** for the different solutions given in this post (`1.00` is the best and reference time):

[image]

(*the test list `b` is Ciao's random list with parameter `n` as the given "size":*)

```
SeedRandom[299];
b = RandomChoice[
  {9, 1, 1, 1, 9} -> 
   {{{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {4, 5, 6}}, 
    {{}, {}, {}}, {{}, {{{}, {{}}, {}}}, {}}, {{}}, 
    {{1, 2, 3}, {}, {{{{{{{{{{{{1, 2, 3, {{{}, {1, 2, 3}}}}}}}}}}}}}}},
     {1,2, 3, {}}}}, n];
```